# Regarding sender in contact form

Tags: webforms, emails

I have used [**smtp authentication**](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module in which I have mentioned my `email` and `password`. But I don't want that email id be the sender of the mail in contact form. I want to send mail through another email id which will not have password.

Could anyone help me in the above issue?

Comment: what you have set in email field of configuration >> settings >> site information will be use as sender of mail.

Comment: another email id